# How to transform this code that prints a hollow diamond to solid diamond?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Hello I'm fairly new to python and have a question I'm stuck on:

This is the original code to print a hollow diamond:

```
def print_diamond(height):
    """prints hollow diamond"""
    print("{:^{}}".format("*", height))
    for i in range(1, height // 2):
        print("{:^{}}".format("*" + " " * (2*i - 1) + "*", height))
    for i in range(height // 2, 0, -1):
        print("{:^{}}".format("*" + " " * (2*i - 1) + "*", height))
    
    print("{:^{}}".format("*", height))
    
#test code
print_diamond(5)

print_diamond(3)

print_diamond(7)
```

This outputs:

```
  *  
 * * 
*   *
 * * 
  *  
 * 
* *
 * 
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *
```

How would you transform this code to print a solid diamond?

```
*
 *
***
 *
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Using these tests:

```
print_diamond(1)
print_diamond(2)
print_diamond(3)
print_diamond(4)
```

I tried changing the formatting by adding " * " but that pushes the other " * " on the side. Thank you.

Adding " * " to the spaces " " does not fix the problem as the formating does not work with solid diamond test code.

It shouldn't output this currently:

```
*
*
* 
***
* 
 * 
***
 *
```

Comment: Look for the places in your function that print spaces between stars.

Comment: Welcome Shaylee, you should google tutorials like [this one from gfg](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/programs-printing-pyramid-patterns-python/amp/) before posting a question

Comment: Look at my new edit

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `" "` with `"*"` in the following lines :

```
print("{:^{}}".format("*" + "*" * (2*i - 1) + "*", height))
```

Comment: Using test code print_diamond(2) makes all the asterisks on the left also print_diamond(1) prints a asterick on two lines